# How to remove Activity layout flickers when switching from full screen activity to normal activity(with Action Bar)?

Tags: android, layout, screen, splash-screen

I am using a splash screen of full screen size no action bar layout but When I move to Login activity which is normal activity having action bar my layout does not move smoothly it shows some flickers(up/down).I am not getting over it please help ...

I am using Intent to pass action from splash activity to login activity

this is my code of splash screen:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        /* set time to splash out */
        final int welcomeScreenDisplay = 4000;
        /* create a thread to show splash up to splash time */
        Thread welcomeThread = new Thread() {
            int wait = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    super.run();
                    /*
                     * use while to get the splash time. Use sleep() to increase
                     * the wait variable for every 100L.
                     */
                    while (wait < welcomeScreenDisplay) {
                        sleep(100);
                        wait += 100;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("EXc=" + e);
                } finally {
                    /*
                     * Called after splash times up. Do some action after splash
                     * times up. Here we moved to another main activity class
                     */
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                            LoginActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        welcomeThread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the code of your splash activity

Comment: I have posted the splash activity code here

Answer (score 0):

use this instead to create the delay

```
/** Duration of wait **/
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

        /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity 
         * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,Menu.class);
                Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                Splash.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for response ,But this does not helped me.Do you think animation may be a way to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

launch your activity as

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,Menu.class);
                mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                Splash.this.overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                Splash.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is solves your problem.

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));

    // for activity animation.
    //overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    finish();
```